# How to check if a string is in this format "12:30-14:30" using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm in a rush so I don't have time to review regex rules.

I would like to know how do I check if a string is in this format "12:30-14:30", where

1. the start time has to be before the end time.
2. the minute section has to be ":00" or ":30".
3. the hour section is between "08:" and "20:".

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Regex doesn't do math, so determining whether a certain time is earlier or later in the day will be ugly. You can validate your input via regex with regards to rules 2. and 3., but I suggest processing the result with `java.time` to validate the order.

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/16320675) (and corresponding question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex answer is:

```
^((0[8-9]|1[0-9]|20):[03]0)-((0[8-9]|1[0-9]|20):[03]0)$
```

Note that this does not ensure that the start time is before the end time, you would need additional Java code to do that.